# How they steam those TV channel on their website?

Tags: wordpress, web, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, live-tracking

Here is the website. 
http://www.jagobd.com

This is a Bangladeshi website. They are steaming Bangladeshi TV. After embedding their iframe, those does not works any more.

I want to make such type of site. I choose wordpress. How do I can steam TV channel live on my site?

Answer (score 0):

if you can't beat them,join them

```
<style>
.outer
{
width:720px;
height:480px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}
#inner
{
position:absolute;
top:-120px;
left:-10px;
width:1920px;
height:1080px;
}
</style>
<div class="outer">
<iframe src="https://www.jagobd.com/asiantv" id="inner" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</div>
```